# Diff. Eq. solution by inspection

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Ran into an interesting problem that is bugging me!

Determine by inspection a solution to this differential equation:

**4y'' = y**

What this says to me is that we must find a function that if we differentiate twice and then multiply that by 4 we get the original function (y). Any ideas?

Comment: What functions do you know that are equal to their derivative? Could you then modify it to get any constant out front? Hint: think exponentially.

Comment: Got it, e raised to the (1/2)x power! Thank you.

Comment: Assuming you can already do $y''=y$, see if there is a slight change you can make for this case.

Answer (score 0):

How about $y(t)=e^{1/2t}$? $y'(t)=1/2e^{1/2t}$ and $y''(t)=1/4e^{1/2t}=1/4y(t)$. Generally for these questions one of $e,\sin, or \cos$ are good places to start, trig especially if you see some weird minus signs floating around.

Comment: I dont think so because if we multiply the double derivative by 4 we get 16e^2t.

Comment: I think I got it! e^[(1/2)x]

Comment: oops you are completely correct, didnt read carefully, will edit.

Answer (score 0):

first divide by 4 $$y''-\frac{1}{4}y=0\\r^2-\frac{1}{4}=0\\r=\pm \frac{1}{2} \\ \to y=c_1 e^{r_1x}+c_2 e^{r_2x}\\y=c_1 e^{\frac{1}{2}x}+c_2 e^{\frac{-1}{2}x}$$ let's exam the solution
$$y=c_1 e^{\frac{1}{2}x}+c_2 e^{\frac{-1}{2}x}\\ \to y'=\frac{1}{2}c_1 e^{\frac{1}{2}x}+\frac{-1}{2}c_2 e^{\frac{-1}{2}x}\\ \to 
y''=(\frac{1}{2})^2c_1 e^{\frac{1}{2}x}+(\frac{-1}{2})^2c_2 e^{\frac{-1}{2}x}\\ to \\ y''=(\frac{1}{4})(c_1 e^{\frac{1}{2}x}+c_2 e^{\frac{-1}{2}x})=\frac{1}{4} y $$

Comment: So both e^(1/2)x and e^(-1/2)x are both solutions? Is that what you mean when you sum together? Just confused by your last line.

Comment: You are missing another apostrophe on your last two lines.

Comment: This isn’t really solving the equation “by inspection,” though, is it?

Comment: No ,this not . but you can guess $y=e^{ax}$ is an answer . apply this to equation and find $a$